# Porque el valor cityName me da el error de undefined ?. Como capturar el valor que retorna el metodo getClinicValuePage dentro de onClinicChangePage

Tags: html, jquery, input

Esto se mostrará en una fuente monoespaciada. Los primeros cuatro espacios
serán eliminados, pero todos los demás espacios se conservarán.

```
El markdown y el HTML están desactivados en los bloques de código:
<i>Esto no está en itálica</i>, y [esto no es un enlace](https://example.com)
```

Comment: Deberias de agregar tu HTML

Comment: ¿Qué muestra el `console.log` que tienes en la función `getClinicValuePage`? Por otra parte, tu pregunta no tiene cuerpo, explica al menos brevemente qué es lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Lo que me pasa es que cuando llamo al metodo getClinicValuePage me retorna una ciudad Medellin Bogota CaliSur o Barranquilla y funciona perfectamente, pero cuando llamo a esa funcion   para capturarla en la variable cityName me dice que el valor cityName es undefined.